# Procedure returns query table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, navicat

I try to create a procedure that return a query table from Postgresql, but I'm stuck at creating the procedure

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "sap_data"."get_emp_number"(dep VARCHAR)
     RETURNS TEMP TABLE (
                    emp_id VARCHAR,
                    department VARCHAR)
     AS $BODY$
     BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT
            emp_id,
            department
        FROM
            emp_data
        WHERE
            department = dep
    END;$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

When I save this procedure, this error occurs:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE"
> LINE 2:  RETURNS TABLE (

I want to return this as a query so I can query this table using parameter to filter it.

Comment: Did you copy & paste your code? Because there's no space between the quotation mark and the bracket: `"get_emp_number"(dep VARCHAR)`

Answer (score 3):

There are several errors in the creation.

- It is function.
- Functions can't return a temporal table.
- You should prefix columns with a table name in RETURN QUERY SELECT.
- The semicolon before END is needed.

it might look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function "get_emp_number"(dep VARCHAR)
     RETURNS TABLE (
                    emp_id VARCHAR,
                    department VARCHAR)
     AS $BODY$
     BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT
            emp_data.emp_id,
            emp_data.department
        FROM
            emp_data
        WHERE
            emp_data.department = dep;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
```